# Storing image path into textbox of multiple image

Tags: php

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var fileList = [];
var i = 0;

$(".slider-dropzone").dropzone({
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    url: "/job_work/job_work/CreatejobController/uploadSliderImage",
    maxFiles: 10,
    maxFilesize: 2,
    init: function () {
        $(this.element).addClass("dropzone");
        this.on("success", function (file, serverFileName) {
            try {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(serverFileName));
                $('#filepath').val(serverFileName);

            }
            catch{

            }
            // } catch (err) {
            //     fileList = [];
            //     swal('Error uploading', serverFileName);

            // }
        });
```

It will works only for one image upload. when I will upload multiple image last image path is store into textbox.. how to append image path into textbox.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are rewriting the textarea value
you need to use this code

```
var text =  $('#filepath').val();
text = text + serverFileName;
$('#filepath').val(text);
```

instead of this line

```
 $('#filepath').val(serverFileName);
```